# Email selected data in view

Tags: views, forms, webforms

I have a view which lists items of food.

I would like to give the user a select box so that they can choose the quantity of the food item and then submit the view as a form. This will then need to be sent as an email.

Comment: please could you be more elaborate as what you did till now ??